# stack around variable corrupted

Tags: c, stack, hamming-code, stack-corruption

It crashes with a debug error and says stack around variable 'code' was corrupted. This is code for a hamming code lab I am doing.  The input file is just a bunch of 1's and 0's on the same line.  Why is it crashing?

```
void processFile(FILE* read, char* InMessage) {
    int i = 0, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; !feof(read); i++) {
            InMessage[i] = fgetc(read);
        count++;
    }

    InMessage[count] = '\0';
}

void hammingCode(char* InMessage) {
    int len = strlen(InMessage), i = 0, j = 0;
    char code[12], temp[1000];

    temp[0] = '\0';

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j++) {
        code[j] = InMessage[i];
        if (j == 10) {
            j = 0;

            decode(code);
            code[11] = '\0';
            strcat_s(temp, sizeof(char)*1000, code);
        }
    }

    strcpy_s(InMessage, sizeof(char)*1000, temp);
}

void decode(char* codeWord) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, parity[4] = {0}, diffParity[4] = {0}, twoPower = 0, readNSkip =     0, bitSum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        twoPower = (int)pow((double)2, i);

        for (j = twoPower; j <= 12; j++) {
            if (readNSkip <= twoPower) {
                if (j != twoPower)  {
                    parity[i] += codeWord[j-2] - 48;
                }
                readNSkip++;
            }
            else {
                if (readNSkip == twoPower*2)
                    readNSkip = 0;
                readNSkip++;
            }
        }

        if (parity[i] % 2 == 0)
            parity[i] = 0;
        else
            parity[i] = 1;

        if ((codeWord[twoPower-1] - 48) != parity[i])
            diffParity[i] = 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        twoPower = (int)pow((double)2, i);
        bitSum += diffParity[i]*twoPower;
    }

    codeWord[bitSum] = !codeWord[bitSum];

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code in your debugger ?

Comment: try gdb ./a.out and then type r and press enter and see why it crashes..and fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems I see here:

1. It looks to me like you are calculating the size of the `InMessage` buffer incorrectly in your `hammingCode` function:

   ```
   int len = strlen(InMessage), i = 0, j = 0;
   ```

   The `strlen` function determines the length of the string by finding the position of the first null terminator. If `InMessage` is not cleared, then this could give you some strange lengths as it will contain a random sequence of bytes. Conversely, if you have cleared the buffer then `len` will be 0.

   To overcome this problem, it is better for the caller to provide the size of the buffer:

   ```
   int hammingCode (char *InMessage, size_t messageSize)
   ```

   And use `messageSize` in place of `len`.

   It's advisable to use this same strategy for your other two functions as well as currently there is a chance of overflowing the provided buffers.
2. Following on from the previous problem, it may be that the `decode` function is writing outside the bounds of the buffer. Providing the length of the buffer to `decode` and adding the appropriate checks to ensure the function does not write outside the given bounds would be a good idea.